# SQL request in pandas

Tags: sql, pandas, python-requests

I need to get the user’s current and previous tariff.

```
d = {'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3], 'tariff_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1], 
'date_change':['2022-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-02-10', '2023-03- 
01', '2022-05-07', '2023-06-08']}
change_tariff= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
change_tariff
```

I did it by sorting and selecting the last two values in the loop for each unique user_id

Can I get a more elegant solution?

```
change_tariff_sort=change_tariff.sort_values(by='date_change')

answ=pd.DataFrame()
for i in pd.unique(change_tariff_sort.user_id): 
    answ=answ.append(change_tariff_sort[change_tariff_sort.user_id==i].tail(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the values by `user_id` and `date` and then use `.groupby()` + `.tail(2)`:

```py
change_tariff = change_tariff.sort_values(by=["user_id", "date_change"])

out = change_tariff.groupby("user_id").tail(2)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   user_id  tariff_id date_change
1        1          2  2023-01-01
2        1          3  2023-02-10
4        2          3  2022-05-07
3        3          4  2023-03-01
5        3          1  2023-06-08
```

Comment: Thank you! It is so obviously, I should have known.